# Add an icon to indicate "Already seen"

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

On the main [question list](https://stackoverflow.com/), it would be helpful to see an icon that tells me if I have already seen the question (have opened and read it), or highlight the visited questions.

Comment: Doesn't your browser do this for you? Should a question be highlighted as *"seen"* if e.g. it gets edited? What about answers?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: On most other sites on the net, sure! On SO... lol good luck seeing the difference.

Comment: @NathanTuggy it is a touch... subtle, now you mention it!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I had to hack up a CSS fix for it a while back, using Stylish. It's not pretty.

Comment: Knowing if you've *opened* it is easy enough; how is it supposed to figure out whether you've *read* it?

Comment: I think the `:visited` style is even _more_ subtle than it used to be (evidence: my hazy memory and a cursory glance)

Comment: I think css should be improved for visited. And the key point with read questions - is to exclude it from main list. I look to main list, i see question that i don't know answer, and i don't want see it more... if it possible... And in this case, i can work with questions like with queue!!! Receive new question: answer or mark as read, and my queue is empty...

Comment: As an alternative to just an enhanced `:visited` style (since some browsers handle those differently and some users may clear their history) maybe sync the post ID with the user's account to indicate it's been "visited" programmatically? I'm not sure the load that would create when viewing a large list of posts, just wanted to throw it out there.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Are you able to share your stylish fix?

Comment: @DavidPostill: [Working on it](https://github.com/Room-11/StyleFixer/issues/4), but at present it's pretty messy: it overwrites :visited on a number of links that really shouldn't be or that need different handling (i.e., links to tabs, share/edit/flag/close/delete, and a few others).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That already exists, only it's extremely subtle. When you visit a question, your browser will automatically color the link differently.

[image: Visited vs not]

Perhaps there's a room for a tiny bit more prominent `a:visited` color.

Comment: if talk frankly, i don't see this difference) and i agree with you)

Comment: Yeah, nothing really visible for me. Should be have more difference